# How to remove unnecessary Less errors in "Error List" panel of Visual Studio

Tags: css, visual-studio, less, web-essentials

I'm using Visual Studio 2013 (Update 4) with the Web Essentials extension for a site that uses Less stylesheets.  In one Less file, I reference a mixin (`.box-shadow`) that is defined in another Less file.  The Less files compile correctly because the file that defines the mixin is imported before the file that uses the mixin.  However, Visual Studio doesn't pick up on this and fills my "Eror List" panel full of Less errors:

[image]

Is there a way to indicate to Visual Studio that this mixin is properly defined in another file?  I'd prefer not to turn off Less errors completely because they often are useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to import the mixins file in every .less file for not having those errors.

for example:

```
@import (reference) "mixins.less";
```

@import (reference) will import external files, but without adding the imported styles to the compiled output unless referenced